# Increase transfer rate with Link Agreggation

Tags: switch

I'm researching a way to increase the **file transfer rate** between **one PC and a Server** that are connected with a [D-Link DGS-1210-28 Switch](http://us.dlink.com/products/business-solutions/28-port-gigabit-web-smart-switch-including-4-gigabit-sfp-ports/) in my local network.

Reading the specs of this switch i found "Link Aggregation" feature. As both the PC and the Server have 2 NICs I thought it would help me. So I googled it hoping it would solve my problem, but instead of helping me, this research only brought me more doubts.

Se here is the question:

[image: Network]

- If I aggregate both NICs on my server and both NICs on my PC, like the image above, will I double the file transfer rate between the computer A and the Server (200 MB/s file transfer rate)?
- If the answer is yes, what kind of link aggregation should I use?

Comment: That depends on whether or not your hosts (hosts are off-topic here) can do this. Normally, you have a flow use a single link, so the bandwidth of a single flow, e.g. a single file transfer, is not increased. With multiple flows, you will see an aggregate bandwidth increase.

Comment: Keep in mind that bandwidth refers to the maximum capable transfer rate while speed refers to the actual rate at which the data is transferred. They're 2 different things, you must understand. Think of bandwidth as a large room and two guys in that room tossing a ball as speed. While the speed of the ball is decided with how hard you throw it, you can throw it anywhere within that room (bandwidth). Similarly, when you use link aggregation, you increase the bandwidth, but not necessarily the speed.

Comment: So guys what can I do to actually increase the transfer speed?

Comment: Google "ip load-sharing by host"

Comment: This is actually a really qood question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, no.  All the aggregaion schemes I know of do not load-balance a single flow.  Whereas you may get 200Mbps capability out from your end-devices by some operating system trickery, unfortunately you will use only one of the bundled links from the switch to each end-device, so will not increase throughput.

If you had two PCs then the server may be able to get 100Mbps to each, because the flows could each use a different path.

Answer (score 1):

The link aggregation group (LAG) type must be supported and match on both the endpoint and the networking device.  NIC teaming is a term that you might google along with the make/model of your respective endpoint NIC cards and or OS version.

[Microsoft indicates](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831648(v=ws.11).aspx):

> NIC Teaming, also known as load balancing and failover (LBFO), allows
>   multiple network adapters on a computer to be placed into a team for
>   the following purposes:
>
> - **Bandwidth aggregation**
> - Traffic failover to prevent connectivity loss    in the event of a network component failure

Comment: Will it increase the transfer speed?

Comment: Hashing can be configured to use layer 3 or even layer 4 addressing.  Google "ip load-sharing by host" for specifics.

Comment: That will not turn two 1GB interfaces into one 2GB interface. The hash function will select *one* link for the traffic flow.

Comment: Not true, in case of server running VM's.  " Theoretically, a virtual machine can use more bandwidth than a single physical NIC can provide." https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2006129